# MPQ3904 LTSPICE Model

Tags: amplifier, analog, ltspice, simulation

I'm trying to do some LTSPICE simulations using a MPQ3904 NPN BJT. Of course this specific model is not in the LTSPICE library. I tried to look up possible models online but I can't find anything.

The closest model built into LTSPICE is the 2N3904 but I don't think this is the same.

I'm looking at the MPQ3904 datasheet trying to see which parameters I need to change but I can't figure it out since the datasheet doesn't have beta, VA, VTN, or anything like that!
http://www.ic72.com/pdf_file/m/184636.pdf

Any help or guidance with this would be appreciate!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Beta is the same as hFE, which is the DC forward transfer characteristic in common emitter configuration.

Comment: The parameters look very close to a 2N3904, I think you could just use that.

Comment: Did you try searching the web for "MPQ3904 spice"?  The first link that pops up (for me) [is this one](https://my.centralsemi.com/product/partpage2.php?part=MPQ3904) and there's [a MPQ3904.LIB link](https://www.centralsemi.com/docs/csm/MPQ3904.LIB) halfway down the page.  Not the same manufacturer, but it's likely equivalent.  I also want to echo that this part seems to simply be a quad 2N3904 so the built-in LTspice model should be sufficient.